# I read that it is necessary to have a synthetic tezos token on L2. Why is it not possible to use simple Tezos XTZ?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

I read that it is necessary to have a synthetic tezos token on L2. Why is it not possible to use simple Tezos XTZ?

[Question from Agora](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/media-attention-regarding-tezos-mumbai-upgrade/5211/2)